# Simulink UDP Send Callback

Tags: matlab, networking, udp, simulink

How can I access the callbacks for the "UDP Send" Block (from Instrument Control Toolbox) in Simulink?

I want to send UDP data as fast as it is available in Simulink. After a short amount of time running my Simulink model the Simulation stops as "an asynchronous write is already in progress".
I would like to send whenever the status of that block is '{idle}', however I haven't found a way to access this information.

I also tried to write the function myself in a matlab script within the Simulink model, but code generation is not supported for udp class.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the UDP Send block doesn't give you access to that.

However, you can use `coder.extrinsic(function_name_1, ...)` to build your own MATLAB block.